# how to get records between particular time using linq query in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to fetch records between time 8 pm to 6 am . how to write where clause to get the records between 8 pm and 6 am only.
Code

```
  model = model.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime)).Where(x=>x.status=="UP").Take(100).ToList();
```

sample data

```
1   39  6/28/2017 12:08:43 PM   UP
2   39  6/28/2017 12:04:18 PM   UP
3   39  6/28/2017 11:49:45 AM   UP
```

data type

```
public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

controller

```
 binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
```

Comment: Ok so SQL would use the word between how would you as a human decide if its between two dates/times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DateTime.Hour is more than 8pm or less that 6 AM

```
model = model.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime)).Where(x=>x.status=="UP" && (UpdatedTime.Hour > 20 || UpdatedTime.Hour < 6)).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: Theres no reference to UpdateTime in David's code, did you copy or type it?

Comment: giving error - UpdatedTime Doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Will this return records where the time is 8:14pm?

Answer (score 0):

```
model = model.Where(x=> {
    var timeOfDay = DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime).TimeOfDay; 
    return x.status=="UP" && 
        (timeOfDay.TotalHours >= 20 ||  timeOfDay.TotalHours < 6);
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime)).Take(100).ToList();
```

should verify that the time is on or after 8pm, and prior to 6am.